# Обработка ошибок Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Пробую написать первое приложение Spring MVC:
на стороне клиента имеется форма ввода с тремя полями, пользователь заполняет и нажатием на кнопку отправляет POST запрос на сервер, где этот запрос обрабатывается предварительно проверив введенные пользователем данные.
Подскажите как правильно обработать ошибку ввода данных пользователя и передать ее на сторону клиента, т.е. как правильно сообщить пользователю что именно он сделал не так?

Comment: Введенные данные нужно валидировать как на фронтеде так и на бекенде. Загугугли как валидировать формы в html. В случае правильной валидации в html, в бекенде сможет выскачить ошибка в том случае, если клиент отправил запрос не через форму на сайте, а вручную. В таком случае спасет бекенд валидация, которая просто не пропустит данные и редиректнет пользователя допустим или сам можешь решить, что будет делать в случае невалидных данных.

Comment: В документации всё написано https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: тут описаны стандартные проверки данных, а если мне нужно выполнить свою проверку, например пользователь выбрал какую-то вещь, а в данный момент ее уже нет в базе, или есть но другого цвета, и т.д. Как сообщить об этом пользователю?